# Python: issues with nested {dict : {dict : [list] } } structure and regex matching

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I've been trying to figure out an issue I'm having with nested dictionaries/lists.

```
import re
sentence_list = ["the quick brown fox", "ellie the elephant", "the lion, the witch and the wardrobe", "lion and tiger and elephant, oh my!"]

animal_dict = {"lion":[], "fox":[], "tiger":[], 'elephant':[]}

sentence_dict = {}

for s in sentence_list:
    sentence_dict[s] = animal_dict

for sentence in sentence_dict:
    for w in sentence_dict[sentence]:    
        for m in re.finditer(w,sentence):   
            sentence_dict[sentence][w].append(m.start(0))


print sentence_dict
```

It's giving me the following output, i.e. it's appending the values to every list for every sentence in the dict, not just the current one:

```
{'the quick brown fox': {'tiger': [9], 'lion': [4, 0], 'fox': [16], 'elephant': [19, 10]}, \
'the lion, the witch and the wardrobe': {'tiger': [9], 'lion': [4, 0], 'fox': [16], 'elephant': [19, 10]}, \
'lion and tiger and elephant, oh my!': {'tiger': [9], 'lion': [4, 0], 'fox': [16], 'elephant': [19, 10]}, \
'ellie the elephant': {'tiger': [9], 'lion': [4, 0], 'fox': [16], 'elephant': [19, 10]}}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: As far as I can determine, the code is doing just what you are instructing it to do.  You will need to answer @zondo 's question above.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear enough - @Joshua Snider 's answer below is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want your output to show the indexes where animal names appear in each sentence.

```
import re
sentence_list = ["the quick brown fox", "ellie the elephant", "the lion, the witch and the wardrobe", "lion and tiger and elephant, oh my!"]

animal_list = ["lion", "fox", "tiger", 'elephant']

sentence_dict = {}

for s in sentence_list:
  sentence_dict[s] = {}
  for a in animal_list:
    sentence_dict[s][a] = []

for sentence in sentence_dict:
    for w in animal_list:
        for m in re.finditer(w, sentence):
            sentence_dict[sentence][w].append(m.start(0))


print sentence_dict
```

The above code has the following output:

```
{'the quick brown fox': {'tiger': [], 'lion': [], 'fox': [16], 'elephant': []}, 'the lion, the witch and the wardrobe': {'tiger': [], 'lion': [4], 'fox': [], 'elephant': []}, 'lion and tiger and elephant, oh my!': {'tiger': [9], 'lion': [0], 'fox': [], 'elephant': [19]}, 'ellie the elephant': {'tiger': [], 'lion': [], 'fox': [], 'elephant': [10]}}
```

The reason your code wasn't working is because lists in your animal_dict are the same object and therefore instead of keeping a separate list for each sentence / animal pair each animal shared the same list across sentences.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I wanted to do! This was driving me bonkers.